# Exporting Google Cloud Storage files to Google Drive

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, apache-beam

Is there a way to export Google Cloud Storage files to Google Drive using Python?

I was doing the Google Dataflow tutorial using the Google Shell, which is basically a single apache_beam command. I noticed that the command takes an output destination which is a Google Storage location. I wanted to know if, after the command is run, does Google provide a way to take the output and export it to Google Drive.

Comment: Download the file to your machine upload it to google drive.   what have you tried?

Comment: Thanks Dalm, I saw that as a potential solution but I would prefer just moving straight from the Google Cloud to Drive and eliminate my machine from the chain.

Comment: you could write the download/upload as server code in Java/python/node and host it on Google AppEngine. That way the data never leaves Google datacentres so is quick and doesn't tie up any of your own resources.

Answer (score 0):

Google does not have any mechanism in place for developers to allow for movement of files between their services.

You will need to download your file from Google cloud to your own machine then upload it to google drive.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I thought trying to do this combining Google Cloud Pub/Sub (to know when a file was added to storage) and Google Cloud Functions (to be notified of a new file and call some sort of Drive API) in some way. but it's very possible I'm misunderstanding those features.