# How to move files directly from google drive to google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I am looking to transfer about 1.5GB files from google drive to google cloud platform but I could not find a way of doing it directly.

Any way except the manual download and upload

Comment: Manul only, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54124414/4495081

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google Colab to do that.
Check the answer on this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64190058/7458669)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a script that uses [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads) to download and [Cloud Storage Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) to upload.